# GCC Optimization: Error caused by fgets

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, amazon-ec2, fgets

I compiled code on my Mac with the GCC Optimization Flag `-O3` on to accelerate the execution time. This perfectly worked on my local machine and lead to a speed increase by 2/3.

However, I tried to compile the code on the Amazon EC2, since I am dealing with a large dataset. Using the `-O3` optimization flag causes the following warning

> warning: call to ‘__fgets_chk_warn’ declared with attribute warning: 
>   fgets called with bigger size than length of destination buffer

In the respective function, a text file is parsed line by line. However, I do not really understand why I end up with the warning. The code of the function reads as follows:

```
int loadPriceData(const char *filename, double *target) {
    char line[40];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 80, fp) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%lf\n", target + i);
        i += 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i; // Return number of elements
}
```

`target` is a pointer to an array with `10000` elements by default. The number of entries is not known in advance, but returned by the function.

Comment: `40 < 80`. Doesn't seem too cryptic.

Comment: The problem is that line is an array of 40 bytes but you tell frets that it has 80 bytes. Use sizeof(line) instead of 80.

Comment: Let's extend the warning: `fgets called with bigger size (which is 80) than length of destination buffer (which is 40)`

Comment: ugh, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!

Comment: @mscnvrsy So replace the call to `fgets` as: `fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed calling `fgets(line, 80, fp)`, but the destination array `line` is defined as an array of `40` char.  The compiler on the Amazon EC2 is better configured or smarter than yours.  This is a real bug if the file contains lines longer than 39 bytes.

Incidentally, the compiler invoked as `gcc` on the Mac is usually an instance of `clang`. Try `gcc --version`.

Note that your program does not check if too much data is read, nor if the `sscanf()` conversion succeeds.  Both lead to undefined behavior.

Here is a safer version:

```
int loadPriceData(const char *filename, double *target, int nb_items) {
    char line[80];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        if (i < nb_items) {
            if (sscanf(line, "%lf", target + i) != 1)
                target[i] = 0;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i; // Return number of elements
}
```